# Is there a way to prevent duplicates in an array with stacked queries in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a simple sort feature in Google Sheets by having data validation drop-down lists and using an array of queries. I can get it to work but if a row matches more than one of the data validation drop down lists, then it will appear twice in the array.

I have tried using `vlookup` instead but don't really understand how that works as I can only find very specific examples. I have tried using "`=ARRRAYFORMULA`" and putting my queries inside there but that does not solve the issue either.

My cell currently is

```
={ IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B2)),
    QUERY('App Data Sheet'!1:1006, " select * where B = '"&B2&"'", 0), "");
   IF(NOT(ISBLANK(C2)), 
    QUERY('App Data Sheet'!1:1006, " select * where C = '"&C2&"'", 0), "")
}
```

where B2 and C2 are data validation cells in the active sheet.

You can view my Query Sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AgvDIjmn2tv9_zKj7o5MPYZ9CdX9mZ_tM66n5jp5NEY/edit?usp=sharing

I currently only have two drop-down lists but will want to add more later once I figure out the duplicates issue.

EDIT:
I know that you can use `countif` to see if there are duplicates in a range but I do not how to enter that into my code to prevent it from showing.

EDIT2:

Well, I figured it out. I simply needed to encapsulate my formula inside a `=UNIQUE()` function that I had not known about before. Hopefully, this post will still help someone else out.

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Sorry, I moved the sheet back to domain view only after I found a solution.  I put my answer both in an edit above and in an answer down below. Thank you for taking the time to look at my question anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. I simply needed to encapsulate my formula inside a `=UNIQUE()` function that I had not known about before. Hopefully, this post will still help someone else out.

Googling using the proper words is what made a big difference in finding a solution. Instead of saying that I wanted to prevent duplicates, I searched to only show unique rows.